# Cambiar de color columna fecha en mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un campo en una tabla de mi BD que se llama fehca , mi duda es comopuedo hacer que al mostrarla en mi sentencia php cambie de color dependiendo de la condicion de la fecha , por ejemplo 
si han pasado 14 dias desde la fecha el color mostrado  sera rojo
si han pasado 8 dias debe ser amarillo 
si han pasado 5 dias debe ser verde

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que el campo fecha se muestre en otros colores dependiendo de la condición,no se como se podria hacer eso

```
  $alumnos="SELECT * FROM contribuyente $where $limit";
  $resAlumnos=$conexion->query($alumnos);
  $resCarreras=$conexion->query($alumnos);

  if(mysqli_num_rows($resAlumnos)==0)
  {
  $mensaje="<h1>No hay registros que coincidan con su criterio de búsqueda.</h1>";
   }
   ?>

  <?php include 'partials/menu.php';?>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="starter-template">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h2><strong>Bienvenido</strong> <?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"]["nombre"]; ?></h2>
            <p>Panel de control | <span class="label label-info"><?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"]["privilegio"] == 1 ? 'Admin' : 'Cliente'; ?></span></p>
            <p>
                <a href="cerrar-sesion.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Cerrar sesión</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div><!-- /.container -->
  <?php include 'partials/footer.php';?>
  <section class="box"> 
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Folio" name="nombre"/>

            <button name="buscar" type="submit" class="button special icon fa-search ">Buscar</button>
                  ";
        </form></section>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table">
            <tr class="odd gradeX">
                <th>Folio</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Rut</th>
                <th>Correo</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th>Direccion</th>
                <th>Poste</th>
                <th>Solicitud</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Borrar</th>
                <th>Reporte</th>
                <th>Enviar</th>

            </tr>

            <?php

            while ($registro = $resAlumnos->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
            {

                    echo "<tr class='success'>";
                   echo "<form action ='guardar.php' method= 'POST'>";
                    echo "<td>$registro[0]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$registro[1]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$registro[2]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$registro[3]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$registro[4]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$registro[5]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$registro[6]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$registro[7]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$registro[10]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$registro[8]</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='admin.php?id=$registro[0]&idborrar=2'><img src='./images/eliminar.png' class='img-rounded'/></a></td>";
                    echo "<ul class='actions'>";
                    echo "<td><a href='actualizar.php?id=$registro[0]'><img src='./images/editar.png' class='img-rounded'></td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='enviarmail.php?id=$registro[0]'><img src='./images/enviar.png' class='img-rounded'></td>";
                    echo "</ul>";
                    echo "</form>";



                echo "</tr>";
             }

            echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Sino pones tu codigo es muy dificil ayudarte

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías colocar el código en el que necesitas ayuda?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con javascript.

1.Obtén el dato con JS del lugar donde lo necesitas. Normalmente si lo tienes en una tabla  lo puedes obtener con innerHTML haciendo referencia a la clase del elemento.

Tienes algo así 
< th class="fecha">Firstname < /th>

```html
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("fecha");
```

2. Procura usar el formato que tienen las fechas en JS https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp Te recomendaría que crearas un objeto Date.
3. Haz las condiciones en base al objeto date que creaste y el objeto que haga referencia al día de hoy. Si las condiciones se cumplen, puedes cambiar el estilo de tu fila completa

document.TUELEMENTO.style.backgroundColor = "red";

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo una solución desde PHP. Allí al crear la tabla enviarás la fecha a una función que va a comparar los días transcurridos entre esa fecha y la fecha actual (o cualquier otra fecha que desees) y en base a eso le asignará al valor fecha una clase CSS con el color.

Luego, vía CSS aplicarás el color.

Te muestro un ejemplo completo.

### Código PHP

**EDIT:** Versión optimizada, prescindimos del `switch`, buscando el valor del color en un array basándonos en la cantidad de días. Ganamos en claridad y en escritura de código, sobre todo en caso de tener que evaluar muchas opciones.

Yo he simulado un array con tus datos, a partir del cual se construye la tabla.

```
<?php

    /*Datos desde donde se construye la tabla*/
    $arrDatos=array(
                        array("folio"=>155, "nombre"=>"Juana", "fecha"=>"2018-05-09"),
                        array("folio"=>156, "nombre"=>"Luisa", "fecha"=>"2018-05-15"),
                        array("folio"=>157, "nombre"=>"Daniela", "fecha"=>"2018-05-18"),
                        array("folio"=>158, "nombre"=>"Camila", "fecha"=>"2018-05-22"),
                );

    /*Vamos a crear una variable a la cual le iremos concatenando los elementos de la tabla*/
    $tableHTML='<table class="my-table">';
    /*Obtenemos encabezados de forma dinámica*/
    $arrHeaders=array_keys($arrDatos[0]);
    $tableHeaders= '<thead><th>'.implode('</th><th>', $arrHeaders).'</th></thead>';
    $tableHTML.=$tableHeaders;

    foreach ($arrDatos as $items) {
        $tableHTML.='<tr>';    
        foreach ($items as $k=>$v) {
            $td='<td>';
            /*Aquí, cuando sea la clave "fecha", asignaremos el dato evaluando con la función checkDates*/
            $td.=($k=="fecha") ? checkDates($v) : $v;
            $td.='</td>';            
            $tableHTML.=$td;            
        }
        $tableHTML.='</tr>';
    }

    $tableHTML.='</table>';
    echo $tableHTML;


    /*Función para comparar las fechas*/
    function checkDates($strDate){
        $dateThis = new DateTime($strDate);
        $dateToday = new DateTime('now');

        /*
           *Cuando usamos diff obtenemos un objeto en el
           *cual se encuentran, entre otros datos
           *la diferencia en días. La propiedad es days
        */
        $diffDays = $dateToday->diff($dateThis)->days;
        //echo $diffDays.PHP_EOL;

        $arrColors = array('green'=>5, 'yellow'=>8, 'red'=>14);

        $ifColor=array_search($diffDays, $arrColors);
        $cssColor=($ifColor) ? 'color-'.$ifColor : 'color-black';

        return '<span class="'.$cssColor.'">'.$strDate.'</span>'; 
    }
?>
```

La salida de este código será algo así:

```
<table class="my-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>folio</th>
            <th>nombre</th>
            <th>fecha</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr>
        <td>155</td>
        <td>Juana</td>
        <td><span class="color-red">2018-05-09</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>156</td>
        <td>Luisa</td>
        <td><span class="color-yellow">2018-05-15</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>157</td>
        <td>Daniela</td>
        <td><span class="color-green">2018-05-18</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>158</td>
        <td>Camila</td>
        <td><span class="color-black">2018-05-22</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

### Código CSS

El código CSS que establece el color es tan sencillo como esto:

```
.color-yellow {
    color:#ffd500; /*Puede que yellow sea difícil de ver*/
}

.color-green {
    color:green;
}

.color-red {
    color:red;
}
```

Vamos a ver un fragmento de código de la salida de nuestra tabla, combinado con CSS:

```css
<style>
.my-table {
 border-collapse:collapse;
 width:100%;
}

.my-table td,.my-table th {
 border:0px solid black;
 padding:4px;
}

.my-table tr:nth-child(even) {
 background-color:#f2f2f2;
}

.my-table tr:hover {
 background-color:#ddd;
}

.my-table th {
 padding-top:12px;
 padding-bottom:12px;
 text-align:left;
 background-color:#7f7fff;
 color:#fff;
}

.color-yellow {
 color:#ffd500;
}

.color-green {
 color:green;
}

.color-red {
 color:red;
}
```

```html
    <table class="my-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>folio</th>
                <th>nombre</th>
                <th>fecha</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tr>
            <td>155</td>
            <td>Juana</td>
            <td><span class="color-red">2018-05-09</span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>156</td>
            <td>Luisa</td>
            <td><span class="color-yellow">2018-05-15</span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>157</td>
            <td>Daniela</td>
            <td><span class="color-green">2018-05-18</span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>158</td>
            <td>Camila</td>
            <td><span class="color-black">2018-05-22</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Como lo puedo hacer para que los datos de las fechas mostradas sean extraídos desde la base de datos primero y mostrarlo con colores ,

Comment: @Daniela tendrías que lanzar una consulta a la base de datos que te genere la información en forma de un array parecido a `$arrDatos`. Son procedimientos habituales. Aquí mismo en Stackoverfkow hay varias respuestas que explican cómo se hace.

Comment: esa es mi sentencia para acceder a la BD $alumnos="SELECT * FROM contribuyente ";
  $resAlumnos=$conexion->query($alumnos);
  $resCarreras=$conexion->query($alumnos);                                  
         <?php
            while ($registro = $resAlumnos >fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
            {
                    echo "<tr class='success'>";
                   echo "<form action ='guardar.php' method= 'POST'>";
                    echo "<td>$registro[10]</td>";
                el registro 10 es el que muestra la fecha pero e tratado de modificarlo a un array pero no entiendo como

Comment: @Daniela luego te pongo un ejemplo,.ahora estoy desde el móvil y se me hace más complicado.

Comment: Gracias seria de gran ayuda .

Comment: @Daniela, sería algo así: `$alumnos="SELECT * FROM contribuyente";
$resAlumnos=$conexion->query($alumnos);

while($row = $resAlumnos->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
 $arrAlumnos[] = $row;
}
/*Prueba de los datos*/
var_dump($arrAlumnos);`. O sea, recorres los resultados de la consulta y los vas guardando en la variable `$arrAlumnos`, luego usas esa variable en el código para producir la tabla. En el ejemplo de la respuesta esa variable se llama `$arrDatos`, aquí, se creará una variable `$arrAlumnos` con todos los datos obtenidos en el `SELECT`.