# Asignar el color de cada fila de acuerdo a un dato de la fila

Tags: php, html, mysql

Como puedo cambiar el color de algunos datos extraídos de mi BD, por ejemplo que si está en pendiente sea amarillo y cuando esté resuelto sea verde .

```
  <?php
  $con=@mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'bdpagina');
      if(!$con){
    die("imposible conectarse: ".mysqli_error($con));
}
if (@mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Connect failed: ".mysqli_connect_errno()." : ". 
   mysqli_connect_error());
}
$action = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])&& $_REQUEST['action'] !=NULL)? 
$_REQUEST['action']:'';
if($action == 'ajax'){
include 'pagination.php'; 
$page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))? 
$_REQUEST['page']:1;
$per_page = 10; //la cantidad de registros que desea mostrar
$adjacents  = 4; //brecha entre páginas después de varios adyacentes
$offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
//Cuenta el número total de filas de la tabla*/
$count_query   = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM contribuyente ");
if ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query)){$numrows = $row['numrows'];}
$total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
$reload = 'index.php';

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM contribuyente  order by id LIMIT $offset,$per_page");

if ($numrows>0){
  ?>
<table class="my-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Folio</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Rut</th>
      <th>Correo</th>
      <th>Telefono</th>
      <th>Direccion</th>
      <th>Poste</th>
      <th>Solicitud</th>
      <th>Fecha</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
      <th>Borrar</th>
      <th>Reporte</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
  while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row[0];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[1];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[2];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[3];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[4];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[5];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[6];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[7];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[8];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[9];?></td>
      <?php echo "<td><a href='admin.php?id=$row[0]&idborrar=2'><img src='./images/eliminar.png' class='img-rounded'/></a></td>";
       echo "<td><a href='actualizar.php?id=$row[0]'><img src='./images/editar.png' class='img-rounded'></td>";?>

    </tr>
    <?php
  }
  ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Danila [¿esto no te sirvió?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/166917/29967). Aplicando la misma lógica puedes cambiar el color de cualquier otro elemento, sea el color de una celda de la tabla, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con `bgcolor`, un ejemplo simple es el siguiente:

```html
<table>
  <tr bgcolor="red">
    <td>Texto</td>
    <td>Texto</td>
    <td>Texto</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="yellow">
    <td>Texto</td>
    <td>Texto</td>
    <td>Texto</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor='#00FF00'>
    <td>Texto</td>
    <td>Texto</td>
    <td>Texto</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor='#00F'>
    <td>Texto</td>
    <td>Texto</td>
    <td>Texto</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

También puedes asignarle valores hexadecimales como `#00FF00` ó `#00F` para otros colores que necesites.

Luego para tu caso en particular solo vasta con colocar un `if` de php en el `<tr>` para cambiar dicha fila de color según el valor de estado, suponiendo que el 0 es para pendiente y 1 para resuelto el código quedaría así:

```
    <table class="my-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Folio</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Rut</th>
      <th>Correo</th>
      <th>Telefono</th>
      <th>Direccion</th>
      <th>Poste</th>
      <th>Solicitud</th>
      <th>Fecha</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
      <th>Borrar</th>
      <th>Reporte</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    ?>
<!-- Justo aqui debajo -->
    <tr bgcolor="<?php if($row[8]==1) echo 'green';else echo 'yellow' ?>" >
      <td><?php echo $row[0];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[1];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[2];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[3];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[4];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[5];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[6];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[7];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[8];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row[9];?></td>
      <?php echo "<td><a href='admin.php?id=$row[0]&idborrar=2'><img src='./images/eliminar.png' class='img-rounded'/></a></td>";
       echo "<td><a href='actualizar.php?id=$row[0]'><img src='./images/editar.png' class='img-rounded'></td>";?>

    </tr>
    <?php  }  ?>
</table>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Hola, probe con el codigo pero aun asi no me muestra los colores asignados

Comment: @Daniela, en el código hice una suposición, ¿el color de la fila depende de la variable estado (`$row[8]`) o de que variable? y ¿cuales son los valores de la variable para cada color?

Comment: depende de la variable $row[8] , y las variables para cada color son Pendiente y Resuelto  hice esto <td bgcolor="<?php if($row[8]=='Pendiente') echo 'green';else echo 'yellow' ?>" > y me muestra el color pero no me muestra las letras solo color

Comment: @Daniela, los estilos de tu plantilla se sobreponen al html, puedes probar poniendo `font` a tus celdas de esta forma: `<td><font color="#000"><?php echo $row[7];?></font></td>`

Comment: he estado implementando el código, pero tengo un problema, solo me cambia el color al momento que se refresca la página, 1 segundo aprox. Estoy usando el chrome, por favor su ayuda...

Answer (score 1):

Lo más fácil, para evitar tener que comprobar el valor que vas a usar para asignar el color a la fila, cada vez que imprimas la fila, es usar ese valor como clase CSS para esa fila y añadir esa clase en tus estilos con el color que quieres como fondo. De otro modo si tuvieras varios colores según diferentes valores el código se volvería complicado.

He simplificado el código para el ejemplo, donde sólo se imprimen "nombre" y "estado" para cada fila. Se imprimen con fondo verde las filas donde el "estado" sea *"Resuelto"*, de forma que obtenemos una tabla como la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código PHP:

```
<?php
/**
 * https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168598
 *
 * Cambiar el color de las filas de una tabla según un valor
 *
 */

    $rows = [
        [
            'name'   => 'Foo',
            'status' => 'Resuelto',
        ],
        [
            'name'   => 'Baz',
            'status' => 'Resuelto',
        ],
        [
            'name'   => 'Bart',
            'status' => 'Pendiente',
        ],
        [
            'name'   => 'John Doe',
            'status' => 'Resuelto',
        ],
        [
            'name'   => 'Fake',
            'status' => 'Pendiente',
        ],
    ];

?>

<style type="text/css">
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid grey;
    }
    th {
        background: lightgrey;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    th, td {
        min-width: 200px;
        padding  : 9px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .resuelto {
        background: #1fe039; /* green for solved status */
    }
</style>

<table class="my-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<?php

    $row_position = 0;
    $rows_number  = count($rows);

    // each iteration prints a file
    while ($row_position < $rows_number) {

        echo '<tr class="' . $rows[$row_position]['status'] . '">';

        echo '<td>' . $rows[$row_position]['name']   . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $rows[$row_position]['status'] . '</td>';

        echo '</tr>';

        $row_position++;
    }

?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

> Editado

Ahora, para asignar otros colores de fondo para las filas según el "estado", solo tienes que añadir en tus estilos las clases correspondientes a esos estados, por ejemplo para imprimir con fondo amarillo las filas con estado "pendiente" añade la clase:

```
.pendiente {
    background: yellow:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es mejor usar con las filas de un celda `"id"` de una base de datos, sabiendo que son pares e impares algo así por ejemplo
`id=1`, `id=2`, etc...

```
if(#row['id']%2==0){ // si el id es 1, es impar
    tablitas
}else //sino, es par
    tabilitas
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por la Información, he resuelto satisfactoriamente;

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM detalleconduce';
                foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
                    
                    ?>
                     <tr bgcolor="<?php if($row['habilitado']==0) echo 'gray';else echo 'white' ?>" >
                        <td><?php echo $row['conduce']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['descripcion']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['racionesprimarias']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['racionessecundarias']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['totalraciones']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['totalbruto']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['totalmasitebis']; ?></td>
                        
                        <td><a href="#edit_<?php echo $row['conduce']; ?>" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal">
                            <span class="bi bi-pencil-square"></span> Editarss</a></td>

                        <td><button type="button" title="Imprimir Conduce" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">
                            <a href="../mpdf/index2.php?conduce=<?php echo $row['conduce']; ?>"><i class="bi bi-printer"></i>Imprimi</button>
                        </td>

                        <td><button type="button" title="Imprimir Grupo" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">
                            <a href="../mpdf/index.php?tirada=<?php echo $row['tirada']; ?>"><i class="bi bi-printer"></i>Imprimi</button>
                        </td> 

                        <td><a href="#delete_<?php echo $row['conduce']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal"><span class="bi bi-trash"></span> Deshabilitar</a></td>

                        <td><a href="#habilitar_<?php echo $row['conduce']; ?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="modal"><span class="bi bi-save"></span> Habilitar</a></td>
                            
                        <?php include('BorrarEditarModal.php'); ?>
                    </tr>
                    <?php 
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                echo "Hubo un problema en la conexión: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código y cómo es que responde a la pregunta. Recuerda que la respuesta debe ser útil no solo para ti, sino para los demás miembros de la comunidad. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.